# Why does BeautifulSoup not get all html on Google?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've seen this before but I've never seen anything related to Google. When something is searched on Google, all of the links and titles are put in h3 tags. However, if i try to use Beautiful Soup, none of the h3 tags appear and it seems like a lot of the tags are missing. I don't think this is a JavaScript issue. Is there anything I'm missing?

```
link = "http://google.com/search?q=" + input
soup = BeautifulSoup(link, "lxml")

for item in soup.find_all("h3"):
    print (item)
```

Edit: code

Comment: Can you please show the code which you are using to scrape Google?

Comment: just put it. thought i did it earlier

Comment: Please check the answer by me

Comment: @DIDieureSeyee Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `requests` to get the data. And narrow down your search in order to print only the `titles`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
link = "http://google.com/search?q=" + input("Enter search")
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'}
r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html5lib')

headings = soup.find_all('h3', class_ = 'LC20lb DKV0Md')

for heading in headings:
    print(heading.text)
```

Output:

```
Enter search>? beautifulsoup
Beautiful Soup Documentation — Beautiful Soup 4.9.0 ...
Beautiful Soup: We called him Tortoise because he taught us.
Beautiful Soup documentation - Crummy
beautifulsoup4 · PyPI
Intro to Beautiful Soup | Programming Historian
Beautiful Soup (HTML parser) - Wikipedia
Implementing Web Scraping in Python with BeautifulSoup ...
Tutorial: Web Scraping with Python Using Beautiful Soup
Beautiful Soup - Quick Guide - Tutorialspoint
```

Comment: It will be better if you add code to replace space to `+` and `+` to `%20`

Comment: It might break if you enter strings with spaces like `hello world`

Comment: It doesn't. Input: `Enter search>? history of python`
Results: `Python (programming language) - Wikipedia
History of Python - Wikipedia
History of Python - GeeksforGeeks
Python History - javatpoint
Python Tutorial: History and Philosophy of Python
History of Python - Tutorialspoint
History of Python Programming - Tutorialspoint
General Python FAQ — Python 2.7.18 documentation`

Comment: Interesting. I wrote some programs to search google using Javascript and HTML, there it failed and I expected python requests will fail too

Comment: this ended up working swimmingly! I have a question about some of the things though, Is there anyway i can make this work for more pages (More than 5-7 results)? Also, why the weird class? I thought that all of the classes were different for results.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you get the empty result because you didn't send any request for example via `requests` module as other people in the answers mentioned. You just passed it right into `beautifulsoup` and he doesn't know what to do with it.

Also, it's because there's no [`user-agent` aka `headers`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) specified, and Google could block a request eventually. [What is my `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent)

Code (*`CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)*):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
  'User-agent':
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "python memes",
  "hl": "en"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text, 'lxml')

# container will all title and links. Iterating over each title and link
for result in soup.select('.yuRUbf'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  url = result.a['href']
  print(f'{title}, {url}\n')

---------
'''
35 Funny And Best Python Programming Memes - CodeItBro, https://www.codeitbro.com/funny-python-programming-memes/

ML Memes (@python.memes_) • Instagram photos and videos, https://www.instagram.com/python.memes_/?hl=en
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The differences are is that you only need to iterate over JSON string rather than scraping everything from scratch and don't worry about bypass blocks from Google or trying to understand how to scrape data from JavaScript, e.g. Google Maps or extract images from Google Images since it's already done for the end-user.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "python memes",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
  title = result['title']
  url = result['link']
  print(f'{title}, {url}\n')

---------
'''
35 Funny And Best Python Programming Memes - CodeItBro, https://www.codeitbro.com/funny-python-programming-memes/

ML Memes (@python.memes_) • Instagram photos and videos, https://www.instagram.com/python.memes_/?hl=en
...
'''
```

P.S. - I wrote a more detailed blog post about how to scrape [Google Organic Results](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-organic-search-with-python-3hp5).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the source code of the webpage using `requests` module and then you can pass it to `BeautifulSoup` constructor (also don't use `input` as variable name):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Input = input("Enter search string: ")
link = "http://google.com/search?q=" + Input
html = requests.get(link).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for item in soup.find_all("h3"):
    print (item.text)
```

You can made the input fail safe too. In google search URL you should replace the spaces by `+` and `+` by `%20`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Input = input("Enter search string: ")
Input = Input.replace(" ","+").replace("+","%20")
link = "http://google.com/search?q=" + Input
html = requests.get(link).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for item in soup.find_all("h3"):
    print (item.text)
```

If you don't have the `requests`

Comment: i tried the code and it ended up displaying nothing. Does this work with everything or is it just a my side problem?